# Spring Boot - SSL setup (./well-known/pki-validation)

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am new to SSL setup, please excuse me if my question is wrong.

I have deployed a Spring Boot application on AWS EC2 (Windows) instance with bunch of restful services, exposed through public IP address (AWS), i am able to access them publicly(http). I want to SSL(https) them now. I am in process of purchasing certificate, in one of the steps to setup, they have given these lines to validate a text file, is anyone aware of this ? Can you please suggest where i need to create **./well-known/pki-validation** folder on my Spring Boot application(Tomcat) ?

*The issuing vendor will provide you with a simple text-based file to place in sub-folders /.well-known/pki-validation/ in your site’s "home directory". If done properly, the vendor can view this file via HTTP:// and then issue the certificate upon confirmation.*

Answer (score 1):

## 1 Install certboot in the server.

```
 git clone https://github.com/certbot/certbot
 cd certbot
 ./certbot-auto --help
```

## 2 Obtain the certificate

In order to obtain the certificate you need to expose trough the server certain files. I do that using the target folder of spring boot tomcat.

```
./certbot-auto certonly --webroot -w {SpringBootProjectDir}/target/classes/static/ -d {yourDomain.com}
```

This command obtains the certificates and leaves them in:

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/{yourDomain.com}/
```

Tomcat can't read the certificate provided since its not in p12 format. We have to generate the cert in this format. Use this command

```
sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/{yourDomain.com}/fullchain.pem -inkey /etc/letsencrypt/live/{yourDomain.com}/privkey.pem -out /etc/letsencrypt/live/{yourDomain.com}/keystore.p12   -name tomcat  -CAfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/{yourDomain.com}/chain.pem    -caname root
```

It will ask you a password. Keep the password.

## 3 Configure the server

```
server.port=443

server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store: /etc/letsencrypt/live/{yourDomain.com}/keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: {password}
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

Restart the server and Thats it!

Comment: Please include tags.